# Norm of matrix with denumerable index set

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $S$ be a denumerable set. Let $\ell_1$ be the set of vectors $x$ indexed by $S$, such that $\sum_{i \in S} |x_i| < \infty$.

Let $P$ denote a matrix indexed by $S$ in both dimensions, and let $\Vert P \Vert := \sup_{i \in S} \sum_{j \in S} |P_{i,j}| < \infty$. i.e. finite maximum row-sum of absolute values.

I have two questions in this context, and I'm not sure how to justify:

If we think of $x$ as a column vector, is the inner product $x^T P$ well-defined?

With the above definition of the norm of $P$, is it implied that $\sup_{j \in S} \sum_{i \in S} |P_{i,j}| < \infty$ ?

I came across the first item (i.e. the inner product being well-defined) in a book about Markov chains without any clear explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first question: Yes.**
$\|P\|<\infty$ implies that $(P_{ij})_{i\in S}$ is bounded for every $j\in S$. So $x^T P$ is well defined.

**The second question: No.**
Consider $S=\mathbb N\setminus\{ 0 \}$ and $P_{ij} = 2^{-j}$ for $i,j\in S$. Then, $\| P \| = 1$ and $\sup_{j\in S} \sum_{i\in S} |P_{ij}| = \infty$.

Comment: Does boundedness of each column entry (in any column), i.e. boundedness of any $P_{i,j}$ suffice to make the inner product finite? Is the reasoning that: since each $P_{i,j}$ in this countable infinite set is bounded, then there exists a finite number say $M$ that upper bounds each of these elements. And since $x$ is absolutely convergent, multiplying each element of $x$ with $M$ is also absolutely convergent, which makes the inner product of absolute terms convergent, and hence finally the inner product convergent.

Comment: The example for the second is illuminating. Thanks. Norm equivalence type of thing does not hold for such infinite dimensions, I guess.

Comment: @shankar614 exactly. Both

Comment: @shankar614 notice that the continuous dual of $\ell_1$ is $\ell_\infty$. So naturally the formal adjoint of $P$ is in general not continuous wrt the operator norm to $\ell_1$.

Comment: Any reference you recommend for gaining familiarity with concepts, like formal adjoint or continuity wrt operator norm? Thanks in advance. I'm a bit of a newbie in this.

Comment: @shankar614 functional analysis usually studies continuous linear operators on function spaces